# Import and export data to Dynamics CRM via web service

Tags: web-services, soap-client, dynamics-crm-online, complextype

I have a client who wants to use Dynamics CRM Online 2015, but they need to sync the data via Web Service (SOAP), from and to CRM.

That web service is designed to work with complex types

I tried with [talend](https://www.talend.com/), but working with complex types is a bit messy.

I don't have enough time to build my own custom solution for this.

Any ideas or tools you can recommend?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

While working for my customers I used Simego and Scribe. Check their websites and see if they fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Azure SQL Database for this purpose. Data export service gels well with Azure Database.